# how can i solve the PermissionError?

Tags: python, path, permissions

I write this code and I have got permission error. how can I solve it?

```
path="D:\\university\\brain network\\autism data set\\ccnsd_healthyfMRI_march2021\\full_harmonized_correlation_matrices\\1. childhood"

data = []
for filename in sorted(glob(path)):
    with open(filename) as f:
        data.append(f.read().split())
```

and this is the error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:\\university\\brain network\\autism data set\\ccnsd_healthyfMRI_march2021\\full_harmonized_correlation_matrices\\1. childhood'
```

I tried to address my folder in jupyternotebook files so I make a new folder in jupyter space to copy the path of this folder and can open the folder but when i copy the path i got the name of folder

Answer (score 0):

You should check to see if the folder that you are storing the data in permits reading by all users. You can see this in file manager (assuming you are using windows) by going to the folder, then going to properties, then to the security tab in the properties menu.